# jQuery play next video on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, video

Im building a page that has dynamically loaded sections stacked upon one another, each section can contain a either an image or a video.  I want to build functionality that when the user scrolls past a video the browser will play the one which is currently in view.

A page may look like:

```
-----------------
[     Header    ]
-----------------
[ Image Section ]   |
[ Image Section ]   |
[ Image Section ]   |
[ Video Section ]   <---- Scroll height a (play first video but not second)
[ Image Section ]   |
[ Image Section ]   |
[ Video Section ]   <---- Scroll height b (play second video but not first)
[ Image Section ]   | 
-----------------
[     Footer    ]
-----------------
```

My problem is, each video section is identified by the same class `'.section_video'`, I'm aware I could attribute unique identifiers to each section, but if there is a way to handle it without doing so it would be great.

Currently, to detect whether I am in view I use this code:

```
 // Checks whether our top offset finds the video container
 function isScrolledIntoView(elem){
     var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
     var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();

     var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top;
     var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height();

     return ((elemBottom >= docViewTop) && (elemTop <= docViewBottom)
         && (elemBottom <= docViewBottom) &&  (elemTop >= docViewTop) );
 }

 // Check whether the player div has been scrolled into view
 function checkIfVideoInView(){
     var player = $('.section_video .video_column video');

     // If true was returned, play the video
     if ( isScrolledIntoView(player) ) {
         player.get(0).play();
     }
 }

 window.onscroll = checkIfVideoInView;
```

I have tried using `$(this).(elem)` as a selector as I thought it would grab the current element in view, but console prompted that the element was undefined.

Could anyone point me in the right direction, or should I bind unique identifiers to each video on page load?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use [`$(elem).each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) And check out all the video elements.
something like that:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    $('.myVid').each(function() {
        if(isInView(this)) {
            this.play();
        } else {
            this.pause();
        }
    });
});
```

and the function:

```
function isInView(el) {
    windowTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    windowButtom = windowTop + $(window).height();
    elTop = $(el).offset().top;
    elButtom = elTop + $(el).height();

    return (elTop >= windowTop && elButtom <= windowButtom);
}
```

**demo http://jsfiddle.net/t52sz0rt/1/**

Comment: perfect - exactly what I needed :) 
JQuery really isn't my strong point, thanks again